# MySQL and rails syntax error

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I configured rails to work fine with Rails 3. I am trying to create a migration, and here it is its code:

```
class CreateObservations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :observations do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :start
      t.integer :end
      t.string :videoID
      t.string :event
      t.string :content

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :observations, [:user_id, :created_at]

  end
end
```

now when I run 'rake db:migrate' I get this strange error:
why?

```
demo_app/test/factories/observations.rb:7:syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER, expecting keyword_end
demo_app/test/factories/observations.rb:12: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I am NOT doing any testing now. Just development. so I run this:

```
 rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development
```

and I get the same error.

here is the code in the factory girl which I dont want to include!!!

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :observation do
    user_id 1
    start 1
    end 1
    videoID "MyString"
    event "MyString"
    content "MyString"
  end
end
```

Comment: What's in demo_app/test/factories/observations.rb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because of using **end** field try to change it to something different

Comment: omg, I just noticed that. is there a way to change that without re creating the whole model?!? or changing loads of files?

Comment: @TestTest You could avoid it by carefully programming around it but it will generally be a pain in the ass. Better suck it up and change your model.

Comment: rake db:drop && rake db:create && rake db:migrate should work

Comment: yeah but I still need to delete my model right? (the views etc etc)

Comment: no, no need to delete your model, first rake db:drop, then delete end from migration then rake db:create && rake db:migrate

Comment: @Test Test: You don't have to drop the table, you can use `rename_column` in a migration and you'd probably want `end_id`.

Comment: yes, you can, change end to end_smth, and don't forget to modify your views

Comment: @mu is too short, yes he can actually, but i don't think that it's a good practice to create another migration just for renaming single column